# Problem with the Analytic theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

The analytic theorem claims that

If $f(t)$ is a bounded and locally integrable function on $t \geq 0$ and
$g(z) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-zt}$ is analytic with $\Re(z) > 0$ and extends holomorphically to an analytic function with $\Re(z) \geq 0$
Then $\int_0^\infty f(t) dt$ exists and equals $g(0)$

The proof starts with:

Let R>0 be large and C the boundary of the region $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq R, \ \Re(z) \geq -\delta \}$
where $\delta>0$ is small enough so that $g(z)$ is holomorphic in and on C.
...

But $g$ isn't defined to be only holomorphic on $\Re(z) \geq 0$ ?

Why can $g$ be holomorphic even when $-\delta<\Re(z)<0$ ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is defined to be holomorphic at a point if it is differentiable in some neighborhood of that point. From this it is clear that if $g$ is holomorphic at $z$, it is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z$. Thus for each $z$ such that $\Re(z)=0$, we have some open ball $B_z$ centered at $z$ on which $g$ is holomorphic. Clearly together these balls cover the set $\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|\leq R,\Re(z)=0\}$, and since this is compact we have some finite subcover. Let $\delta$ be smaller than the smallest radius of any of these (finitely many) balls. Then $g$ is holomorphic on $\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|\leq R,\Re(z)\geq -\delta\}$.